# HTTP PUT Request Body Found Null In Web API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to send a request with HTTP Verb  `[HttpPut]` which reached to my controller but param which I have sent is `Null`. Have seen lot of stack Overflow same thread and tried out but cannot figure out... Weird!

*Class I have Serialized*

```
Content requestContent = new Content();
requestContent.Name = "Name";
requestContent.Value = "Value";
```

*Here is my request body*

```
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

public GetAzureResponseClient(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    _httpClient = httpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));
}

var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestContent); 
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:64288/api/ConnectUs/TestMethod");
var response = _httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync(uri, new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic" + "YourAuthKey");
var responseFromServer = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

*My Web API Controller*

```
public ActionResult<Content> TestMethod([FromBody]Content param)
```

Comment: You'll need to add the header before you `PutAsJsonAsync` as that will actually send the request!

Comment: You'll also need a space between `Basic` and your authentication key in the header!

Comment: Yeah I got your points thanks for the hints man.

Comment: @phuzi That's works fine .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to rewrap the object as JSON when using PutAsJsonAsync:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:64288/api/ConnectUs/TestMethod");
var response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(uri, requestContent); // LOOK HERE
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic" + "YourAuthKey");
var responseFromServer = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need extra serialization and you have to call the Async method with 'await'.

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic" + "YourAuthKey");
        var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:64288/api/ConnectUs/TestMethod");
        var response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(uri, requestContent);
        var responseFromServer = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution

Comment: your welcome dear, does it work for you? or your problem exist?

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help

Comment: As Deniel provided the hints first on my previous post, so accepted that one never mind.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh944690(v%3Dvs.118)

PutAsJsonAsync will serialize the given object of type T, try PutAsync instead

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.putasync?view=netframework-4.8